# Getting error while trying to upload artifact to sonatype repo

Tags: maven, maven-deploy-plugin

I am trying to deploy a 3rd party jar to a sonatype nexus repository using the following command:

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file –DgroupId=com.myartifact -DartifactId=wfeventapi -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT -Dpackaging=jar –Dfile=/Users/ssurendran/code/telemetry/metrics/lib/wf-event-api.jar  -DrepositoryId=sresnapshot –Durl=http://maven.mycompany.com/nexus/content/repositories/sre-snapshots/
```

I get the following error:
*[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix '–Durl=http' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (/Users/ssurendran/.m2/repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]*

Answer (score 0):

maven is thinking '-Durl' is a plugin.  Probably a space or invisible character is creating a problem.